# WAS8, Jersey2 Issue JerseyServletContainerInitializer not a subtype

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy Jersey 2 application in Websphere 8. My pom has following dependency for jersey:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
         <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

And web.xml has following entry:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseyApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.tieto.vam.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JerseyApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In Websphere application server, I have set following property:

```
com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine=true
```

And I am trying to load JAX-RS jars from inside the war, by setting Module class loader to: Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)
When I try to deploy this application (war) in Websphere, I get following error in startup:

```
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:432)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1295)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:316)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:229)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:702)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:406)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:169)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5396)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:250)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:196)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:387)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:415)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:491)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:537)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Does your app contain the Servlet API?  That can't be packaged in a PARENT_LAST application, because the web container needs a consistent version of the API linked at both the application and container scopes.

Comment: @Jarid, Yes, pom contains following entry:       <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>                                           Should I make it provided?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Hello, facing same issue, can you please tell me how the issue was resolved

Comment: @PanayappanSwaminathan you need just change scope of servlet-api dependency from compile to provided:
`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`